# RELAX_VERSION_LOOKUP issue

Tags: deployment, ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x

I get the lookup failure issue in my servers often.

> Unable to get remote handle for BinRemote. : Unable to resolve
>   'BinBean#com.mine.org.bin.BinRemote.qaw10-51865'. Resolved
>   'BinBean#com.mine.org.bin.BinRemote'  Possibly version 'qaw10-51865'
>   of application 'MYJms' was retired.  To relax lookup to return the
>   active version, set context environment property defined by
>   weblogic.jndi.WLContext.RELAX_VERSION_LOOKUP to "true".

I goggled and suggestions were to set `weblogic.jndi.WLContext.RELAX_VERSION_LOOKUP` to `true`. Where shall I do that? I am not good at WL. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found this link, and adding it to jvm options.

http://angraze.wordpress.com/2011/01/29/weblogic-10-3-jndi-issue-with-versioned-app-during-cluster-restart/

Answer (score 0):

To apply RELAX_VERSION_LOOKUP to just one area, use this:

```
Environment env = new Environment();
env.setProperty(weblogic.jndi.WLContext.RELAX_VERSION_LOOKUP, "true");
env.getInitialContext().lookup(...);
```